# Pure CSS Responsive Text Effect

Tags: html, css

my question is very simple. Consider the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rachsmith/pen/BNKJme). Is it possible I can get the same result just using css? in other words, how would this be done without using javascrip? Many Thanks!

```
<div class="text">
 <p>Nachos are</p>
  <p>
   <span class="word wisteria">tasty.</span>
   <span class="word belize">wonderful.</span>
   <span class="word pomegranate">fancy.</span>
   <span class="word green">beautiful.</span>
   <span class="word midnight">cheap.</span>
  </p>
</div>

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}

var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);
```

Comment: You'd probably need to alter the HTML since CSS isn't great at dealing with part words. Is that allowed?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes is allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Yes. Basically that is possible!**

But indeed it is really hard work to calculate the animation to every damned letter ... but I am not quite sure if there are not still some animations studios who are playing arround with such things ...

So, if you want to **exactly** like do that (= with letter animating) I would prefer to use the really nice JS snippet (thx for showing that here).

But if you are however not able/willing to use JS in your project and you would like to do **SOMETHING** like that you can realize a COMPLETE WORD CHANGING easily in CSS using `@keyframes` animations.

See a quick and dirty example for expalanation below.

Note: The animation is really simple! Of course you can do much cooler effects using rotations, backgrounds, etc. If you like just adapt example to your imaginations :-)

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.wordChange__wrapper {
  display: relative;
}

.wordChange__changer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  width: 220px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: wordchanger;
          animation: wordchanger;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
          animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.wordChange__element_1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}

.wordChange__element_2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}

.wordChange__element_3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}

.wordChange__element_4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
          animation-delay: 6s;
}

.wordChange__element_5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
          animation-delay: 8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wordchanger {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  9% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  24.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  29% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes wordchanger {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  9% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  24.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  29% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p class="wordChange__wrapper">Nachos are&nbsp;
        <span class="wordChange__changer wordChange__element_1 wisteria">tasty.</span>
        <span class="wordChange__changer wordChange__element_2 belize">wonderful.</span>
        <span class="wordChange__changer wordChange__element_3 pomegranate">fancy.</span>
        <span class="wordChange__changer wordChange__element_4 green">beautiful.</span>
        <span class="wordChange__changer wordChange__element_5 midnight">cheap.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```