# Chained fadeInDown CSS

Tags: css

I've this animation on CSS to fadeInDown a element for a new one to appears:

```
    @keyframes fadeInText {
    from {
      transform: translateY(0px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(30px);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

But I want one that is chained and soon as the first fades a new ones appears right after. I tried something like creating a second keyframes with the values of X and Y on opposite, but didn't work.

The expect result is something like this. There is a easy way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar question this weekend with same technique.

It is just one sliding down animation wich is set to every text element.

The trick is to start same animation for every text element with delay so it starts when the slide down movement is ready by the elements before.

The calculations to do that are not as easy as they need to be transformed in `percanteges` so you can set them to `@keyframes`.

**Basic expalantion:**

Total `@keyframes` is `100%` (always)
Your animation starts at `0%` (always)
... now example for 2 keyframes-settings:

```
@keyframes textMover{

   0% {
      ... stylings when animation starts
   }
   50% {
      ... stylings when animation ends
   }

   ... this is the part where the animation pauses
   ... and the second animation is running
   ... so nothing changes here

   100% {
      ... same styling after ending all
      ... as this are same stylings as by 50% this is not needed
      ...  so this entry is just for understanding
   }

}


// now you can call

.text1 {
   animation-name: textMover;
   animation-duration: 10s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text2 {
   animation-name: textMover;
   animation-duration: 10s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   
   // here is the trick:
   // animation for element 2 starts delayed 50% of the total animation time 
   // so it start when animation part of first element ended and is 'paused'
   animation-delay: 5s;

}
```

**More COMPLEX running demo example with same effect you are looking for see:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66731214/9268485